# Collection was modified error is comming when i use Application.Exit()

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

when i use Application.Exit() method in my application it is showing an error like

collection was modified exception is comming

how to handle this exception

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312885/application-exit-vs-application-exitthread-vs-environment-exit

Comment: Don't handle an exception like that, fix the bug.  If you have no idea where the bug might be located then post the StackTrace of the exception in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all of your threads are ended before you call `Application.Exit()`