# How to make keypress (keydown) close program

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently writing code for a project in VB.NET where if you hit the "escape" button you get a messagebox saying "This exits the program, would you like to leave? 'Y' or 'N'". What code would I write to make it so that if you hit "Y" the program closes?

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
        MsgBox("This button exits the program. Do you want to exit the program?")
        If Button = e.KeyCode = Keys.Y Then
            End
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Exit`, but I'm not adding an answer as this question [is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146080/closing-applications) (different programming language, but the same framework).

Comment: Use [MessageBox.Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba3x8zfh(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: @cybermonkey, I do appreciate the answer but unfortunately it did not work when I tested it, it must be something in my code.

Comment: You must design a custom message box-like form in order to do that. When Windows's message box is shown it'll both steal focus but also trap the rest of the application in a modal loop. The latter means that the rest of the application will be unable to operate and respond to events (such as `KeyDown`).

Comment: In addition to @Jinx88909's comment you should use `MessageBox.Show()` since that's the native .NET way to do it. `MsgBox()` is a VB implementation in VB6 and older, which currently exists only for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @VisualVincent, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you what you are after:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
        If MessageBox.Show("message", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Screenshot showing how it looks when I press the *Esc* button:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Try This One**

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
        Dim ask As MsgBoxResult
        ask = MsgBox("Close Program ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Exit")
        If ask = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't DV however I did suggest an edit which fixes obvious errors. You could however replace lines 3 to 5 with `If MessageBox.Show("message", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then`

Comment: @Jinx88909 : I reviewed your edit and it looked fine. Two more need to approve it before it's officially approved.

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent appreciate it.

Comment: I Have Checked this code and there is no single problem with this code

Comment: @AliAhmad `dim ask as MsgBoxResult()` was causing an issue. This needed to be changed to `Dim ask As MsgBoxResult`. Note the removing of `()` and you had missed off the `End If` for `If ask`. Apart from that the code was fine. Like I said I didn't DV. Unless the answer is heavily wrong I don't DV.

Answer (score -1):

```
  Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

  Select Case e.KeyCode

       Case Keys.Escape

            Msgbox("Close",vbInformation)
            Me.Close()

   End Select

  End Sub
```

Hope This Helps as a guide.

Comment: I didn't DV but I think the OP would like to ask a question with a _Yes/No_ option and not just show `Msgbox("Close",vbInformation)`