# XamlParseException was unhandled C# app

Tags: c#, xaml, blend, xamlparseexception

I received this error randomly and I don't know how to fix it seeming as the cause of the problem happened out of random.

Can anyone guide me on what I should be looking for, I think it points to my XAML code but I don't know what I should be looking at.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message=Cannot create instance of 'MainWindow' defined in assembly 'Shutdown Timer, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'Shutdown Timer;component/MainWindow.xaml'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=0
  LinePosition=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, Uri baseUri, XamlObjectIds currentXamlObjectIds, XamlObjectIds contextXamlObjectIds, Type objectType)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.ThrowException(ParserContext parserContext, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition, String message, Exception innerException)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.GetElementAndFlags(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementStartRecord, Object& element, ReaderFlags& flags, Type& delayCreatedType, Int16& delayCreatedTypeId)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.BaseReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadElementStartRecord(BamlElementStartRecord bamlElementRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.ReadRecord(BamlRecord bamlRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.Read(Boolean singleRecord)
       at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilderBamlTranslator.ParseFragment()
       at System.Windows.Markup.TreeBuilder.Parse()
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__0(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at Shutdown_Timer.App.Main() in D:\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\Shutdown Timer\Shutdown Timer\obj\x64\Release\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
       Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
            at System.Windows.Markup.BamlRecordReader.CreateInstanceFromType(Type type, Int16 typeId, Boolean throwOnFail)
       InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
            Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            Source=Shutdown Timer
            StackTrace:
                 at Shutdown_Timer.MainWindow..ctor() in D:\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\Shutdown Timer\Shutdown Timer\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 128
            InnerException:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems `Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source=Shutdown Timer. StackTrace: at Shutdown_Timer.MainWindow..ctor()` is the root of this..can you post your MainWindow constructor code? Specifically, it seems to coming from `MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 128`

Comment: Removing this block of code stopped the error from returning, This code is needed though for further functionality, is there anything I'm doing wrong? http://pastebin.com/LwFJSt4P

Comment: You should call `Application.Exit` (which is a graceful close), not `Environment.Exit`.

Comment: Environment.Exit is the Application.Exit for WPF

Comment: Wrong.  [`Application.ShutDown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx).  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905544/whats-difference-between-environment-exit-and-application-shutdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905544/whats-difference-between-environment-exit-and-application-shutdown)

Comment: I have tried System.Windows.Application.Shutdown() but Shutdown is not a listed operation.

Comment: @Sandeep: `Application.Current.ShutDown()`.  It's not a `static` method.

Comment: OK thanks I've changed all instances of Envrionment.Exit() to Application.Current.Shutdown()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bug on line 128 of your code-behind.

**EDIT**: `pinFix` is probably `null`.

Comment: Removing this block of code stopped the error from returning, This code is needed though for further functionality, is there anything I'm doing wrong? http://pastebin.com/LwFJSt4P

Comment: Thanks, I just surrounded the block with a try-catch and now working fine.

Comment: @Sandeep: Instead of silently swallowing errors, you should figure out what's wrong and fix the bug.  Empty `catch` blocks are _evil_.

Comment: Well the main problem is that the registry subkey doesn't exist therefore it throws the error.

Comment: @Sandeep: You should use an `if` statement, not a `catch` block.

Comment: Yep since I've located the problem I'll be using an if statement. Thanks again.