# Application.Exit() isn't working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I have 2 forms (`main` and `login`). I open the login form with this piece of code:

```
toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 50;
toolStripStatusLabel_dynamic.Text = "Proberen toegang te verkrijgen...";
Login login = new Login();
login.ShowDialog();
do_login();
```

And I have a toolstrip menu at the top of the login form with an `eventhandler` like this:

```
private void afsluitenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Application.Exit();
}
```

But after both forms are closed, the program continues to work (it calls the function `do_login`.) But the variables aren't set, and the form is gone, so `do_login` won't work at all...

So how will I make the whole execution of the program stop when I click the toolstrip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to work around it because the definition of `Application.Exit()` is as follows.

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

So what it's saying is once all messages have been **fully** processed it will exit, but since you have a message that needs processed after the dialog closes it has to finish that first. You are doing the exit properly, but you're going to have to check for `null` and return if it is `null` in the `do_Login()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation. But as i don't need to do any other thing, this also worked out: Environment.Exit(0); But thanks anywhay

Comment: @TWCrap - I realize you like that solution because it **kills** the application but I want you to read the responses in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905544/whats-difference-between-environment-exit-and-application-shutdown) before settling on that decision. `Environment.Exit`, unless absolutely necessary, is not a good approach.

Comment: @TWCrap - you can change the accepted answer as well if you are satisfied with the approach I recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe check the result of `ShowDialog` ?

```
using(var login = new Login()) {
    if(login.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        do_login();
    }
}
```

(the `using` is because **you** are responsible for calling `Dispose()` if you use `ShowDialog()`, but *not* when you call `Show()`)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think calling Application.Exit(); is a good way to exit.  For one, it may not allow any other code to execute that may have been put in place to clean up on application shut down.

Instead you should return a DialogResult from Login to indicate that a close is required.  The main form should then check for this and close down gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

Combined with Marc's answer, change `Application.Exit` to `Environment.Exit(0)`.

```
private void afsluitenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.
    Environment.Exit(0);